# VS2015/Git list changes to files even after a hard reset / delete

Tags: git, visual-studio-2015

Some files in my local repo are listed as changed even after I do a hard reset.
Even deleted the local branch and created a new one, and the same files are listed as changed.
Anyone have the same problem, preferably with a solution?

Comment: Tell me about your line endings...

Comment: @EdwardThomson I noticed one line has a tab at the end, but how come this is still registered as a change when I undo? I haven't opened or edited the file.

Comment: I meant:  what is `core.autocrlf` set to?  What are your `gitattributes` set to?

Comment: @EdwardThomson
`core.autocrlf=true`
In `gitattributes`: `text=auto`

Comment: `gitattributes` also got `*.cs text eol=crlf`. The files in question are javascript-files